# exporting variables which are variable values in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, export

When i try to do this...

```
$ export my_path='/my/path\ with\ spaces/file'
$ echo $my_path`
/my/path\ with\ spaces/file
```

It works.

But i want to do this..

```
$ echo $my_variable
my_path='/my/path\ with\ spaces/file'
$ export $my_variable
-bash: export: `with\': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `spaces/file'': not a valid identifier
```

This is the error iam getting. 
Is there a way to treat the value of the variable for exporting.. [[ NOTE: if the path did not have a space, it works perfectly!! ]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the `$`. Otherwise the shell would expand the variable's value before passing it to `export`. The following will work:

```
export my_variable
```

In comments, it points out that you wan't to store the variable assignment itself as a variable and then pass it to `export`. Here comes an example:

```
var='foo=bar'
export "$var"

# check if it succeeded 
export | grep foo # output: declare -x foo="bar"
```

Comment: This works because `export` will expand the value of its arguments. When you say `export $foo` then `foo` will be expanded before being passed to `export` and if `foo` contains spaces, `export` will think it's given several arguments that are names of shell variables.

Comment: actually, my end goal is to export the "my_path" variable. Not the "my_variable" itself.

Comment: Something like this? : `$var='$foo=bar'; export "$var"`

Comment: Not working man.. :(  `bash: export: '$foo=bar': not a valid identifier`

Comment: var='foo=bar'; export "$var"